# How to publish Facebook feed as someone else other than the logged in user?

Tags: facebook

The editors on my news site can publish articles that are written by authors (who don't have permissions to publish stories on their own). So when the articles get published to FB, they are published under the FB profiles of the editors instead.

Does Facebook API allow stream publishing as someone else other than the logged in user?

According to the [wiki documenation](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish), I can specify the author's uid in the api call.
However, it gave me a fatal error code of 210 instead.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookRestClientException' with message '**User not visible**' in /usr/local/share/php_includes/facebook/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php:3065 ...
>
> User not visible. The user doesn't have permission to act on that object.

How to bypass this error?

Comment: quick google search turns up http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=77237 ...  I'm not sure if it's useful...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it's not what I'm encountering

Answer (score 2):

1.) The user must have added(liked) the app

2.) The user must have wall posts enabled (check whether you can post directly to his/her facebook wall (without API)

Comment: That was it, the user must like my app in order to post messages, any way around this? I want any user to post to my wall even if they dislike it...

Answer (score 1):

I never tried that but I guess you're going to need the `offline access` permission in order to achieve that. This grants you the privilege to access a user account without the user being currently logged in your application.

I wrote a [blog post](http://modelix.net/2009/09/facebook-connect-working-with-offline-users-data-access/) about this a few months ago.

Comment: The user has already granted me offline_access so that's not the problem.

But thanks, your post gave me some ideas on how to do it and it's now SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the api call DOES work.
However, it's important to know if the user (the person you are performing actions on - the authors in this case) is a fan of your application.
If they are not a fan, they cannot post on app wall. :(

Comment: There is a difference between LIKE'ing an app, and GRANTING PERMISSION's to an app. I doubt LIKE's effected the posting of the message... I suspect that the user revoked "basic permissions" for your app (http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications). e.g. The user accepted "Access my basic information" permissions to use your app, then removed those permissions latter? ... I could be wrong. Just seems strange that LIKE's would impact your apps permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre Olivier Martel: offline access will bedeprecated soon :
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/